# How to change image colour apart from the certain region

Tags: python, opencv

I am learning opencv to process the image. Suppose I know the coordinate of centre and radius of the red circle, how to change the whole image colour to while except the circle region?

Original image
[image]

Expected image
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please provide a minimal code

Comment: Maybe [my answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55592662/11089932) is helpful to you. The procedure to solve your task is very similar to that one linked.

Comment: @HansHirse thanks. But what if I have text in the circle and I want to keep it. Do you know how to handle it?

Comment: As @ma3oun stated, please share some code, we can have a look on. You can easily generate a mask using [`circle`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaf10604b069374903dbd0f0488cb43670), and set all pixels to any color outside this mask in your input image. That will maintain any content inside the circle.

Comment: @HansHirse Many thanks for your help. I only draw the circle with 1 as thickness, but forget to fill it. After changing the thickness of circle to -1, it works.